# Sqlite attach database and insert data from table A to table B

Tags: android, database, sqlite, insert

I have two sqlite databases and want to copy a table from database A to database B. The other tables in database A should not be copied.
I try to ATTACH database, then use INSERT but have exception "no such table" on attached table.
My code:

```
private final String TABLE_NAME = "LOAD_IMAGES";
private final String COLUMN_UNIT_ID = "UNIT";
private final String COLUMN_LOAD = "LOAD";

public void createTable(){
    String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " ("
            + COLUMN_UNIT_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_LOAD + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";

    database.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

public void insertData() {
    String path = App.filesDir + '/' + "data";
    database.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '" + path + "' AS data;");
    String ADD_DATA_INTO_TABLE = "INSERT INTO '" + TABLE_NAME + "'(" 
    + COLUMN_UNIT_ID + ", " + COLUMN_LOAD +") " +"SELECT " + 
    COLUMN_UNIT_ID + ", " + COLUMN_LOAD + " FROM 'data.IMAGES';";

}
```

Exception log:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: data.IMAGES (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 'LOAD_IMAGES'(UNIT, LOAD) SELECT UNIT, LOAD FROM 'data.IMAGES';
```

I try to write :

```
LOAD FROM data.IMAGES
```

or

```
LOAD FROM 'data'.'IMAGES'
```

or

```
LOAD FROM data'.'IMAGES
```

but nothink changed.

Table of second database "IMAGES" structure: [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FROM 'data.IMAGES'
```

This is interpreted as a plain table name. Remove the quotes.

Comment: Hi, i edit query to: `String ADD_DATA_INTO_TABLE = "INSERT INTO '" + TABLE_NAME +
                     "'(" + COLUMN_UNIT_ID + ", " + COLUMN_LOAD +") " +
                "SELECT " + COLUMN_UNIT_ID + ", " + COLUMN_LOAD + " FROM data.IMAGES;";` But its dont work. `SQLiteException: no such table: data.IMAGES (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO 'LOAD_IMAGES'(UNIT, LOAD) SELECT UNIT, LOAD FROM data.IMAGES;`

Comment: Apparently, that other database file does not exist (at that path).

Comment: Ok, how can I know if database attached ? Maybe some listener?

Comment: Where does the other DB file come from? How do you know that it's there?

Comment: Yes, my db dont attached because i write wrong name of it. Thx for you to help find this mistake. You saved my time.